Unable to Find Mapping for "LnAdd.LnAcctInfo.BorwInfoArray.BorwInfo.BorwInfoTxt" in LnAcctAdd - Receiving Errors
I'm working with Jack Henry's Loan Add Account API through MuleSoft, and I'm encountering an error that I can't resolve. Specifically, I'm unable to find the mapping for the following element in the payload:
LnAdd.LnAcctInfo.BorwInfoArray.BorwInfo.BorwInfoTxt. and LnAdd.LnAcctInfo.UserDefInfoArray.UserDefInfo.UserDefTxt
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><detail><HdrFault xmlns="http://jackhenry.com/jxchange/TPG/2008" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><FaultHdr><JxVer>R2024.0</JxVer><AuditUsrId>mulesoft</AuditUsrId><AuditWsId/><Ver_1/><jXLogTrackingId>ede21d78389</jXLogTrackingId><Ver_2/><InstRtId>999491555</InstRtId><InstEnv>UAT</InstEnv><Ver_3/><BusCorrelId>d04a8e8a323e</BusCorrelId><Ver_4/><Ver_5/><ValidConsmName>sburgFL</ValidConsmName><ValidConsmProd>IDA</ValidConsmProd></FaultHdr><FaultRecInfoArray><FaultMsgRec><ErrCode>130</ErrCode><ErrCat>Error</ErrCat><ErrDesc>The value entered is longer than the field length</ErrDesc><ErrElem>SEVICING OFFICE</ErrElem><ErrElemVal>Little Rock, AR</ErrElemVal><ErrLoc>LNACCTADD</ErrLoc></FaultMsgRec><FaultMsgRec><ErrCode>112</ErrCode><ErrCat>Error</ErrCat><ErrDesc>Description is invalid</ErrDesc><ErrElem>LnAdd.LnAcctInfo.BorwInfoArray.BorwInfo.BorwInfoTxt</ErrElem><ErrElemVal>Credit Score</ErrElemVal><ErrLoc>LNACCTADD</ErrLoc></FaultMsgRec></FaultRecInfoArray></HdrFault></detail>'

What is the correct description for LnAdd.LnAcctInfo.BorwInfoArray.BorwInfo.BorwInfoTxt: Credit score AND LnAdd.LnAcctInfo.UserDefInfoArray.UserDefInfo.UserDefTxt: servicing office?
